# TFIDF: tf implementation

Tags: classification, document-classification, tf-idf

I am implementing a classification tool and was experimenting with various TF versions: two logarithmic (correction inside/outside of the logarithm call), normalized, augmented, and the log-average. Apparently, there is a significant difference in my classifier accuracy modulated by these - as much as 5%. What is odd, however, is that I am unable to say in advance which one would perform better on a given dataset. I wonder if there is some work that I am missing, or, maybe, someone could share experience working with these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the increase in importance by adding a given term to a document should decrease with the number of appearence of the term. For instance, "car" appearing twice in a document implies that the term is much more important than appearing only once. However, if you compare a term appearing 20 times with the same term appearing 19, this difference should be lower.

What you are doing by specifying different normalisations is defining how quick the TF value saturates at some point.

You can try to correlate your findings with some information about average TF per document or similar metrics.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. So, then the difference in performance is likely to be due to the speed of term(s) weight saturation.
Still wonder if you could point some work explaining these models (not sure if it's the right word to use)?

Comment: I am afraid I haven't found any decent related paper...
You might find something looking for weighting schemes, feature weighting or normalisation.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed very hard to tell in advance which weighting scheme would work best. Overall, there is [no free lunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem)- the algorithm which works best for one dataset might be horrible for another. What is more, we are not talking about radically different options here. TF-IDF embodies one specific intuition about classification/retrieval, and all of its different variants are kind of the same. The only way to tell is to experiment

PS A note on terminology: when you say significant, have you done any statistical significance testing with cross-validation or random resampling? It could be that the differences you are seeing are due to chance.

Comment: I train my classifier on train data set (500 instances), and test it on the test data: these do not overlap. With test set of 625 instances, getting 32 wrong just due to TF implementation seems to be significant.